# Oracle query under PHP isn't getting executed with parsing, may be due to date variable of PHP so how to convert date variable into string?

Tags: php, oracle

I am using `Oracle` as the database with my `PHP` code and here is my query in which I'm using environment variables. When I give value to these variables as a string and bind them then the query is getting executed easily.
But when I used `HTML5` `date` input then I am having to change my date-format for which I used following PHP code and bound this PHP variable to Oracle variables. But now the query is not getting executed.

**Part Of Query:**

```
  where trunc(eto_ofr_approv_date_orig) between to_date(:start_date,'DD-MM-YYYY') and to_date(:end_date,'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

**PHP Code:**

```
$start_date=date("d-m-Y",strtotime($start_date));
$end_date=date("d-m-Y",strtotime($end_date));
.
.
.
<QUERY HERE>
.
.
.
$sth = oci_parse($con,$sql);
oci_bind_by_name($sth, ":start_date",$start_date);
oci_bind_by_name($sth, ":end_date",$end_date);
if(oci_execute($sth)){
    echo "OK";
}
 else{
     echo "NO";
}
```

This is always printing `NO` on screen.

BTW my **HTML Code** is as bellow if needed:

```
<label for="start_date">Start Date :</label>
<input type="date" id="start_date" name="start_date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-1 week')); ?>">
<label for="end_date">End Date :</label>
<input type="date" id="end_date" name="end_date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>">
```

Have a look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake.
I created `$con` outside this function so I edited my code and passed `$con` into my function.